# Why does this code cause a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to close a window when OK button is pressed. But when I try to run the file, it gives me a StackOverflowError.

Here is my code:

```
public class Test1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Test1 t = new Test1();
/**
 * Creates new form Test1
 */

public Test1() {
    initComponents();
}
```

And this is the actionListener for the button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        t.setVisible(false);
    }
```

This is the error message,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:11)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    ...and so on
```

Test1.java:11 refers to `public class Test1 extends javax.swing.JFrame` and Test1.java:13 refers to `Test1 t = new Test1();`

What is the problem here? How can I solve it?

Comment: `Test1 t = new Test1();` really? A new `Test1` creates a new `Test1` creates a new `Test1`, ....

Comment: To the downvoter(s), I don't think downvoting a question because the solution is trivial or the error is stupid is a good way to use voting.

Comment: I'm voting for reopening because the question is not asking what a stack overflow is, but what in this specific code is causing it.